# How to get a list of elements listening to a custom event without keeping track of them?

Tags: javascript

From what I've learned from this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events, it seems that I have to manually keep track of the elements listening for a custom event. When dispatching the event I need to do that for every listener.

Is it possible to retrieve the listeners without me keeping track of them? Or that when I dispatch the event I don't have to do that to every listener manually like so:

```
textarea.addEventListener('input', e => e.target.dispatchEvent(eventAwesome));
```

so that it will just dispatch to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [following](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983) can help. Not sure what you need but let's say you have a container with text areas that when input is fired on one then custom is fired on all others.

```js
const hasRole = (el,role) => el.getAttribute("x-role")===role;
const isSomeRole = el => hasRole(el,"some-role");
const customEvent = () => new CustomEvent('custom', {
  bubbles: true
});
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener(
  "input",
  e=>{
    if(!isSomeRole(e.target)){
      return;//not the element we were looking for
    }
    Array.from(
      document.querySelector("#container")
        .querySelectorAll(`[x-role="some-role"]`)
    )
    .filter(el=>el!==e.target)//do not trigger custom on current element
    .forEach(el=>el.dispatchEvent(customEvent()));//trigger custom on all other elements
  }
);

document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener(
  "custom",
  e=>{
    if(!isSomeRole(e.target)){
      return;//not the element we were looking for
    }
    console.log("custom triggered...",e.target.value);
  }
)
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      one
      <textarea x-role="some-role">one</textarea>
      two
      <textarea x-role="some-role">two</textarea>
      ignored
      <textarea x-role="other-role"></textarea>
    </div>
```